# Is a ret instruction required in .NET applications?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I noticed that the C# compiler generates a `ret` instruction at the end of `void` methods:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    // method body
    L_0030: ret 
}
```

I've written a compiler for .NET and it works regardless if I emit a `ret` statement or not (I've checked the generated IL and it's indeed not in there).

I just wonder: Is `ret` on methods returning `void` required for anything? It doesn't seem to do anything with the stack, so I believe it's completely unnecessary for `void` methods, but I'd like to hear from someone who knows a bit more about the CLR?

Comment: (I assume the C# guys emit ret on void method becuase it makes their job easier: Only have one method-generator function in their compiler that is used for void and non-void methods and just always emit ret instead of checking if it's needed. I'm just guessing though)

Comment: you could use .NET reflector to see if it generates any different bytecode.  My guess is absolutely not, because there is no reason for it to.  The guess you mentioned in your comment look right, too.

Comment: @Merlyn No, it doesn't. If I don't emit ret, no ret is emitted in the IL.

Comment: There has to be a ret according to ECMA-335 12.4, 6. `Control is not permitted to simply “fall through” the end of a method. All paths shall terminate with one of these instructions: ret, throw, jmp, or (tail. followed by call, calli, or callvirt).`

Comment: If it works, it works by accident. An unverifiable program is allowed to have implementation-defined behaviour, and implementation-defined behaveiour includes working as you want it to. It's a better idea to use PEVERIFY to ensure that your code generator always generates verifiable code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the C# Standard (ECMA-334), a method is defined as the following:

> A method is a member that implements a computation or action that can be performed by an object or class.
>   Methods have a (possibly empty) list of formal parameters, a return value (unless the method’s return-type is
>   void), and are either static or non-static.

([ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm); 8.7.3: Methods).

Now, the CLI standard defines the following:

> Control is not permitted to simply “fall through” the end of a method. All paths shall terminate
>   with one of these instructions: ret, throw, jmp, or (tail. followed by call, calli, or callvirt).

([ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm); 12.4, 6)

This means, that in C#, a method returning `void` does not need a return statement. However, as the C# compiler compiles the C# code to IL Code, which requires a path termination at the end of a method, it emits a `ret` to end the method.

Answer (score 17):

It is indeed required in order for the code to be verifiable. Otherwise PEVerify will output the following error message:

> [IL]: Error: [(filename) : (methodname)][offset 0x00000000] fall through end of the method without returning

Answer (score 8):

From Ecma-335. (12.4, 6)

> Control is not permitted to simply “fall through” the end of a method. All paths shall terminate
>   with one of these instructions: ret, throw, jmp, or (tail. followed by call, calli, or callvirt).

Comment: Ecma-355 is titled 'Tunnelling of QSIG over SIP'