# Is C++ compiler obligated to generate 'ret' instruction for a function without 'return' statement?

Tags: c++, return

Recently I encountered a problem that a thread in my programe was somehow stopped (GDB indicates thread's state as STOPPED). I have spent a couple of days debugging. This problem happended after I changed the version of the compiler some days ago. Finally I found out that the problem happens because a function is defined with `int` return type but does not have a `return` statement. So the asm code of the function does not have a `ret` instruction. When it reaches the end of the funcion in runtime, since no `ret` instruction exists, execution continues on the next instruction which is in another funciton. This causes the thread being stopped. I have checked the asm code generated by the compiler of previous version, and the same function does have a `ret` instruction.

In my experience, missing `return` statement in a function with non-void return type is not suggested, but should not results in thead stop. I want to know if I am wrong, or the compiler is wrong.

My question is, for a normally ended (not ended by exception, call, jmp...) function with non-void return type, is the compiler obligated to generate a `ret` instruction or not. Does it have any C++ standards or C++ specifications illustrating the compiler behavoir in this case?

*I have done some search and found an answer for c# in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692937/is-a-ret-instruction-required-in-net-applications). How about for C++?*

Comment: In general, the standard doesn't dictate specific asm instructions. It only defines the behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat or doesn't define the behaviour in this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

For any non-void function except main, if there is any path through the function that does not `return`, your program exhibits undefined behaviour if that path is taken at runtime. Then the compiler is allowed to do whatever it feels like. Generally this results in just a missing ret statement but I have seen much weirder effects.

The standard specifies this in **[stmt.return].2**:

> [..] Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a
> non-coroutine function with a cv void return type is equivalent to a
> return with no operand. **Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function
> other than main (6.9.3.1) or a coroutine (9.5.4) results in undefined
> behavior**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: *"if there is any reachable path through the function"* AFAIK the path has to actually be taken to cause UB. E.g. `int foo(bool x) {if (x) return 42;}` is not UB until you actually call `foo(false);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, that wording was off, thank you. I meant reachable during runtime. Let me correct this.

Comment: Which standard is this? Looking at the [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return), it would be `stmt.return.4`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I thought I had the C++20 standard (draft) before me: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But I'm still a little confused about how to understand "undefined behavior". In my previous knowledge, I thought it means the **return value** is undefined since the register holding the return value could has any value and if this return value is used in caller function, it could reults in "**undefined behavior**". Anyhow, the function returns. But in this case, the function does not return after its last statement, and continue executing the following instructions in .text (code) segment. Is this a legal compilation result?

Comment: Assume that all functions don't have a return statement. The compiler would check and add a ret instruction at the end of the function if the function has void return type, and don't add a ret instruction for non-void return type function (so let it run into the following instructions)? Is this the case?

Comment: @WenwenKang Your mental model of what C++ is slightly skewed. At least for this discussion. C++ is a definition of a (somewhat formal) language for an abstract machine. C++ as a language has no concept of registers, stacks and so forth to begin with. What UB (undefined behaviour) means is that a particular piece of code has no semantics according to the formal language. That means that there is *no defined way* for the implementation of your compiler to translate this to the target system. Undefined does not relate to which value should end up where, but what the piece of code means.

Comment: @WenwenKang -- "undefined behavior" means that the standard doesn't tell you what the program does. Speculating about what code the compiler might generate and how that might behave is usually pointless.